# Basic Authentication in Glassfish

Tags: security, glassfish

I am having trouble getting BASIC authentication to work with Glassfish.  I am developing an application and I need to be prompted for a username and password.  I have gotten the application to prompt me for a password when I attempt to access the application, but after entering the correct login information, I get `HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied`.

I have gone into the Glassfish Admin Console and created a few sample users in the `file` realm and enabled the Security Manager.

Next, in my `web.xml` file, I have added the following:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I'm not exactly sure what to do next.  I have searched for several hours with no luck.  The authentication works because if I enter incorrect login information, it prompts again, but after successfully authenticating, I get the access denied message shown above.

If it helps, I am running Glassfish Open Source 3.0.1 and using Netbeans 6.9 for development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if defaults apply but you may need to create *sun-web.xml* and set a mapping for role "User":

```
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  ... 
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
    <group-name>filerealm-group-name</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  ...
</sun-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the Glassfish documentation at http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html is incorrect.

> If the role names used in an
>   application are not the same as the
>   group names defined on the server, use
>   the runtime deployment descriptor to
>   specify the mapping. The following
>   example demonstrates how to do this
>   mapping in the glassfish-web.xml file,
>   which is the file used for web
>   applications

In which case you need to create a WEB-INF/glassfish-web-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
        <group-name>User</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```