# How to implement basic authentication with Glassfish?

Tags: java, linux, security, glassfish, basic-authentication

I'm tried this configuration but it didn't work for me. 
[Basic Authentication in Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892870/basic-authentication-in-glassfish) 
I also tried this guide 
http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/10/13/basic-authentication-in-glassfish-3/ but I couldn't get user-pass asking with it too.

These are steps I've taken:
1. Login as admin to Admin interface.
2. Go to Security->Realms->File
3. Add a group name (Users) to Assign Groups field.
4. Open manage users at the top of the page.
5. Click New and add an user (testuser) and give a password.
6. Add (Users) to Group List.
7. put this lines to web.xml

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

8. and put this lines to sun-web.xml

```xml
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
    <group-name>Users</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

9. After all I enabled Configurations->server-config->Security->Security Manager

My configuration is Glassfish 3.1, sun java6 jdk, Debian lenny and a simple "Hello World" page for testing.

What is missing here?

UPDATE:

I figured out it needs xml headers. After I've added them it started to work. My final configuration is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

and

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
    <group-name>Users</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

Comment: Is step 9 really necessary? I also use file and jdbc realms but never enabled the Security Manager. Just an idea... Your configuration files look fine. You can set logging of javax.enterprise.system.core.security module in Glassfish to FINEST and check your log file for any hints.

Comment: It didn't work without step nine. I figured out that it needs xml headers.

Comment: I wonder exactly the same than @Matt Handy. Any Oracle's tutorial don't tell to enable that. In the latest Netbeans if I enable Security Manager, I can't use Netbeans integrated Glassfish anymore, it just doesn't start anymore.

Comment: I have Glassfish 4.0 and Netbeans 7.3.1 and "sun-web.xml" is not required.  I deleted the file after creating it per your steps.  I did, however, have to edit "glassfish-web.xml" and add lines like this: <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Users</role-name>
        <principal-name>testuser</principal-name>
    </security-role-mapping>  See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this guide: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beaxw/index.html I heard that web.xml sometimes not work properly. I had same problem but cannot test it now.