# How to make sure that an EJB service is only accesible if an user is logged in?

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, ejb

How to make sure that an EJB service is only accesible if an user is logged in?

---

### Simple example

A simple user class, which will be stored in the database:

```
package myproject.ejb.domain;

@Entity
public class User {
    String username, password;
}
```

And some service interface to invite some friends:

```
package myproject.ejb.services;

@Remote
public interface Service {

    /**
     * Invite an user to be friends
     */
    public void invite(User user);
}
```

The service may only be accesible to the Web Application if an user is logged in.

---

Now I'd to know if there is any recommended authentication method for Java EE projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to enforce authentication is by declaring the required roles for accessing a bean. You specify for example that only users with the role "Administrator" can access your Service bean. A quick step by step overview has been given in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912577/how-to-implement-basic-authentication-with-glassfish) question. What you basically do is:

1. Create security realm (in your case JDBCRealm)
2. Insert users and their roles into the realm
3. Add the `<security-constraint>`s to `web.xml` to specify the required roles

For fine grained access control you can use different roles as described in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html)